# Designing a monitor process for monitoring and restarting processes

Tags: c, process, unix

I am designing a monitor process. The job of the monitor process is to monitor a few set of configured processes. When the monitor process detects that a process has gone down, it needs to restart the process.

I am developing the code for my linux system. Here is how I developed a small prototype
- Fed the details(path, arguments) about the various processes that need to be monitored. - The monitor process did the following:
1. Installed a signal handler for SIGCHLD 
2. A fork and execv to start the process to be monitored. Store the pid of the child processes.
3. When a child went down, the parent recevies a SIGCHLD 
4. The signal handler will now be called. The handler will run a for loop on the list of pids stored earlier. For each pid, it will check the /proc filesystem for existence of a directory corresponding to the pid. If the directory doesn't exist, the process is restarted.

Now, my question is this
- Is the above method (to check the /proc filesystem) a standard or recommended mechanism of checking if a process is running or should I do something like creating a pipe for the ps command and looping through the output of ps ?
- Is there a better way of achieving my requirement?

Regards.

Answer (score 5):

You should not be checking `/proc` to determine which process has exited - it's possible for another, unrelated, process to start in the meantime and be coincidentally assigned the same PID.

Instead, within your `SIGCHLD` handler you should use the `waitpid()` system call, in a loop such as:

```
int status;
pid_t child;

while ((child = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0)
{
    /* Process with PID 'child' has exited, handle it */
}
```

(The loop is needed because multiple child processes may exit within a short period of time, but only one SIGCHLD may result).

Comment: I guess this looks like a correct method to do it as in this case I can have my main execute a while(1) loop with sleep(100) inside it. When the child exited, I use the waitpid to determine which one exited and restart that process. This way my main loop is not consuming much resource (it will be in sleep for most of the time). The process will only handle a SIGCHLD(restart the process) and go back to sleep.

Comment: @user500949: As @nos mentions in another comment, if you're going to do this then just place the above loop in `main()` instead, and remove the `WNOHANG` flag.  `waitpid()` will then sleep until a process exits, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Let's see if I've understood you. You have a list of children and you are running a loop on /proc on your SIGCLD handler to see which children are still alive, isn't it?

That's not very usual,... and it's a but ugly,

What you usually do is run a `while((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)))` loop on your SIGCLD handler, and use the returned pid and the Wxxx macros to maintain your children list up to date.

Notice that `wait()` and `waitpid()` are async-signal-safe. The functions you are calling to examine `/proc` are probably not.

Comment: If all you're doing is waiting for child processes, you don't need to do this within a signal handler though. Just call waitpid without WNOHANG, and you don't have to walk the fine line of being async signal safe.

Comment: IMHO having a waitpid in the signal handler would work better as i can execute a while(1) loop in the main with a sleep (100) in it. This way my main will usually be sleeping and not consume any cpu cycles. What do you say ?

Comment: @user500949: If you don't do anything else on your program, `waitpid()` without `WNOHANG` will block (sleep). On the other hand, if you do other things on your program, and can do everything watching file descriptors and waiting for timeouts (using `poll()`, `select()` or equivalent), you can use the self-pipe trick to turn a `SIGCLD` into an event watchable from a file descriptor.

Comment: @user500949  waitpid, without WNOHANG is a blocking call. It's not busy waiting, it'll not consume cpu cycles.

Comment: @ninjalj - Could you explain "you can use the self-pipe trick to turn a SIGCLD into an event watchable from a file descriptor." How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Look into [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/).   It works great.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily tell if a process is alive by issuing a `kill()` system call to its pid. If the child is not alive, `kill()` will not succeed.

Also, calling `waitpid()` with the `WNOHANG` option will return zero immediately if the process is still alive.

IMHO, reading proc files or piping to ps is a nasty way to do it.

Comment: I want my main to be doing as little work as possible so that the cpu resources are not consumed by it. Wouldn't the solutions mentioned above be better in that case ? (Executing waitpid in the signal handler and having a sleep in main)