# How to monitor process life

Tags: c++, linux, process

I have a problem, I have a control executables which monitor few process and if anyone died then it will restart it. On windows we are doing with WaitFOrMultipleObject where process handle passed in the array of handle. If any process die we getting acknowledged by WaitForMultipleObject.

Now we have to implement it on Linux. How we will do it? Wait is only work for one process id and while we have to monitor multiple process.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4126401/designing-a-monitor-process-for-monitoring-and-restarting-processes

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for [process groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group). You can [`waitpid(2)`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Completion.html) for a process group using `-pidgroup` (i.e. the negative value of the pid group) as the value for pid in the call, or `-1` to wait for any child process.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the places where Unix falls down -- it really ought to have a notion of a file descriptor for a process, that could be passed to `select` (which is the Unix equivalent of `WaitForMultipleObjects`); but it doesn't.

What you do instead is install a handler for `SIGCHLD`.  In that handler, you call `wait4` or `waitpid` (whichever is more convenient; but don't try to use plain `wait`, you need the options parameter) in a loop, setting the `WNOHANG` flag, until it returns 0.  For each child, package its PID and exit status into a structure and write that structure to a pipe.  Read from that pipe in your main event loop, pull out the structures and take appropriate action.  DO NOT try to respawn children (or allocate memory, or do *anything* besides call `waitpid` and `write`) from the signal handler, unless your program has nothing else to do and the "main loop" consists of calling `sigsuspend` in an infinite loop.

Comment: That seems to be overcomplicating it when this can be achieved very cleanly by either waiting on any child (-1) or any member of a proess group (-pgid). No need for signal handlers and no busy waiting.

Comment: You still have to call it in a loop if you do that, and if the program has anything else to do, there is no alternative to `SIGCHLD`.  It does now occur to me that if the program has nothing else to do, it could block in `waitpid` rather than using `sigsuspend`.

Comment: If you really want something that you can call select() on then you can always use signalfd() to do it that way.

Comment: That's Linux-specific as far as I know, and it doesn't give you a fd for each process you want to know about.